# Flash AS2: Setting text of textfield through code causes some characters to be deleted

Tags: actionscript-2, textfield, flash-cs6, dynamic-text

I have the following line of code to set the text of a Dynamic textfield:

```
boxCopy.text = 'Coming soon: 30th January 2014';
```

but when I compile the file, it shows as: *'Coming soon: 0th January 201'*

I have no idea why this is. The font character set contains all the numeric characters, so it should display it.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that embedding the font's Lowercase, Uppercase, Numeric and Punctauation charcters fixed the problem. Very strange behaviour through because if I typed it into the dynamic textfield in the scene view it worked fine.

Thought I'd keep this question here in case someone has the same issue.